# How can I improve google search result for my website?

Tags: seo

I have built an extremly small website for fun for the past couple weeks. But after 1 week I put it on the shared host, there is still no Google search result for my site.

Actually, Google has indexed my site's home page which I uploaded 3 weeks ago for test purpose and is always displaying that "test page" when my domain name is searched.

I know Google and other search engine cache data for a reason, **but how long will the cache last until next time they crawl my site?**

[image: Google indexed my home page incorrectly]

Apparently, my website [mymsdn.info](http://mymsdn.info) is now totally different from the one Google collects.

Comment: Why my thread was closed due to SEO cannot be related to programming or software development? In general, SEO refers lots of principles and methodologies. But both of them requires many development jobs, such as minification, meta definition, image sprite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you are looking for can be found [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1352276).

If you have any other questions or need more explanation please let me know.